# Cookie contains multiple values?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm having a problem where I'm adding a persistent cookie using `Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)` but this seems to be adding the value if the user already has a cookie with that name.  I think end up with multiple values in the cookie, which is not what I want.  Should I be using `.Set` instead?

Note that the cookie may contain a value from a previous visit and I wish to overwrite it with a new value, not keep multiple values.

Comment: how are you trying to get the cookies' values sent previously?

Comment: @FelipeOriani Using the `.Value` property of the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason for this is that if you have a cookie `x` and .mydomain.com and try to set another cookie `x` at .subdomain.mydomain.com you end up with both values when you read the cookie `x` from .subdomain.mydomain.com.  The choice of `Add` vs `Set` isn't relevent to my problem then, it was just me misunderstanding how cookies and subdomains interact.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are an associative array, meaning they are a collection of key-value pairs, and like a form, if a given key has more than one value its value will be an array.

Keys are segregated by domain, so google.com can have a cookie with the same name as yours and that shouldn't cause any collisions. How is it that someone has the same cookie name you're trying to set? have they been to your site before?

Perhaps you should try to GET the cookie and then SET updates to it as you suggested.

Comment: No, its all within our one domain this is happening.  I'll go to our site (secure.blah.com, which sets a cookie at blah.com level) and then later I'll come back and the cookie should be replaced with a different value and instead its adding the value.